# How can I loop in a log file that is logging information at the same time that I'm reading it to find a string that I know will eventually appear?

Tags: c#, while-loop, contains, readline

My problem is a bit complicated for my C# level.

I have my while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) with my if (line.Contains(toVerify)). But my problem is that I want the loop to run until it reach a timeout OR it hit the if condition, but not to stop when line = file.ReadLine()) != null.

My log file is logging information at the same time as I'm running my file.ReadLine(), so inventually it will hit my if condition. I've search all day how can I do it before asking here, because I don't want to bother people with my beginners question :).

Thanks in advance

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        string toVerify = "NavMesh generation operations finished";
        string line = "";

        Stream stream = new FileStream("Info-Log.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(stream);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(toVerify))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(toVerify);
                Console.WriteLine("Line number: '{0}'", counter);
                return;
            }

            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why not just have your logger do what ever this is supposed to do when the condition is met?

Comment: The thing is, it's two sperate software. 
One is the main software doing the execution
The other is for automated test. So from the automated test I'm reading the log file generated during the execution of the main software.

Comment: So you're saying you have no access to the main apps code base?

Comment: I assume that you want kind of an infinite loop that always checks if the condition is now true. If i'm right use a `FileSystemWatcher`, so your app is silent until there is something to do.

Comment: Exactly. All I do is using Ranorex to automate some of the UI testing and validate certain steps via the log files

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll look look into that.